Always gets stuck on booting Ubuntu
Everything was working correctly. The problem started when I was using the laptop and it went to sleep mode. While logging back in it got stuck and I force turned it off and then this booting problem started. I tried to check the file system , logs, run hardware test and everything is good, but it still gets stuck here.


Please edit the question and add some basic details. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What have you done to try and fix the problem? Please list what ever you have tried and any errors or messages you get. This will help for others not to tell you to do something you have already tried.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

This was a gnome issue the required gnome-session was not loading so I reinstalled the gdm3 gnome-session ubuntu-desktop. Thus the error was solved.
